# Sharing internet from Mac to Windows in VMware

Tags: macos, vmware-workstation

I am using Macbook pro and installed VMware with Windows 7. I want to share my internet connection from 3G dongle with Windows.I am having Network adaptor settings to NAT. But its showing ! symbol in the network status icon of task bar.

I tried diagnosing problem. But i am not able to troubleshoot the problem.

3G dongle internet was working fine in my old laptop with sharing internet with vmware. I have recently changed my laptop. During that time, I have copied image of vmware from old laptop.

Could this be an issue?

Answer (score 1):

One method you could try, is instead of using 'NAT' as the Network Interface, use a 'Host-only' adapter. And then in network settings, bridge the 'VMware Host Only' adapter and your '3G' adapter.

Comment: Could you please tell me the steps for this? I am not familiar with network settings.

Comment: There are a few options available to bridge networks, I found this page that describes a few ways: http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20060930205108232 . Also, here is some information on how to set a VM to use a Host-only adapter: https://www.vmware.com/support/ws55/doc/ws_net_configurations_hostonly.html